# Center dynamic height/width Image to fixed height/width div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've problem with centering dynamic image to fixed size div. So, the main idea is that image knows how to scale itself whether it is panoramic image or portrait image. The div, I'm aligning to, is close to 16:9 (300x170). Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide any code and what you've tried so far?

Comment: I've tried displaying outer element as table and inner one as table cell and then align it with table css, but without luck. I think it wouldn't work also, if I want the way I described in the OP.
Maybe one small blocker is that the image is one side of CSS3 flip div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SnPR6/)

```
div {
    height: 170px;
    width: 300px;
    border: solid;
    line-height: 170px;
    text-align: center;
}

div img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 170px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. The key was in the max-width, max-height property. Thank you :)